# Why is .profile is not sourced when choosing "Open in Terminal" in context menu?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, gnome-terminal

I have already changed the default profile of the terminal emulator to "Run command as login shell", but that only enabled the sourcing of .profile when I open Terminal via `ctrl-alt-T`. What am I overlooking?

Comment: And you're using http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nautilus-open-terminal?

Comment: That package is installed, but I am not entirely sure it is the one used on this system.

Comment: Edit made, please review

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `nautilus-open-terminal` extension runs the terminal [with a command](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus-open-terminal/blob/master/src/nautilus-open-terminal.c#L303):

```c
/* interactive shell */
command = g_strdup_printf ("cd %s && exec $SHELL", quoted_path);
```

So that particular terminal preference will be ignored, since the terminal is not starting a shell, but running a command. It doesn't look like you can change it without modifying the source.

Comment: made an edit, comment removed. Your answer is correct and  already has my upvote